# Permission management of Docker

Tags: docker

I have a docker in a server, which is shared in our group. However, I find that others can delete the container I create. It is not safe. I am wondering is there a way to set permission for containers. Such in Linux, different user has their different permission to access to a different file.

Comment: Something like that https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2018/Feb/25/multiple-docker/?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone that has direct access to the docker socket (e.g. being added to the docker group) is effectively root on the host. They can run containers as root with the host filesystem and other namespaces mapped into the container, and with privileges that allow a container escape as root on the host. Given that situation, the concern that they have access to other containers on the host seems misdirected.

You should focus on only giving access to the docker API to those you trust as a sysadmin on the host. Everyone else should only have access through tools that implement the appropriate security measures. Often this involves configuring centralized logging and metrics systems, and deploying changes only through a CI/CD system.

Short of that, you can attempt to configure something like OPA as an authz plugin on the docker engine, however you'll need to transition from access to the docker socket over the filesystem to using TLS credentials unique to each individual.

Alternatively, Docker offers an enterprise solution where this functionality is built into the product.